# Deserializing a collection of Objects with Jackson

Tags: android, json, exception, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to build a mobile application using JSON as my primary tool to exchange data between my server and application. I have set up 2 classes that will need eventually need to be deserialized.
This is the class first class:

```
public class AccountCollection {
private ArrayList<Account> accountCollection;
private int count;

public AccountCollection() {};

@JsonProperty("AccountCollection")
public ArrayList<Account> getAccountCollection() {
    return AccountCollection;
}

@JsonProperty("AccountCollection")
public void setAccountCollection(ArrayList<Account> accountCollection) {
    AccountCollection = accountCollection;
}

@JsonProperty("count")
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@JsonProperty("count")
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
}
```

And this is the class for the Account Object:

```
public class Account {
private String uri;
private String accountUID;
private String accountName;
private String description;
private String status;
private String accountlevelstatus;
private boolean shared;
private String targetUID;
private String targetName;
private String targetType;
private String domain;

public Account() {
};

@JsonProperty("uri")
public String getUri() {
    return uri;
}

@JsonProperty("uri")
public void setUri(String uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}
//Getters and setters continue on in the same fashion
```

The problem occurs when I try to deserialize the JSON data I receive. The first object does have the `accountCollection` and `count` variables initialized fine, but when I try to iterate over the collection the `Account` objects all have `null` as their variables. Is there any way I can get the Object Mapper to recognize the `Account` type? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It should be recognized automatically. Could you add example JSON to your question?

Comment: Hey, Michał. I realized that I interpreted the JSON data incorrectly and that it was an error in the way I set up the objects to be mapped. After I fixed that I was able to deserialize the data without a problem. I seem to have forgotten to mark this problem as solved.

Comment: OK, glad to hear it. You can add answer for your question and write where was the problem and how you solved it. Or just delete this question.